# C# Entity Framework many-to-many relationship with quantity

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-design

I'm designing a database to keep inventory of office equipment, but in many cases a room will contain multiples of an identical item, like a conference room with 3 identical TV screens. Storing serial numbers and such isn't important; only quantity matters.

I want to avoid having to re-input the same information over and over again (TV, plasma, 1920x1080, 50", etc etc), so I'd like to simply have, for example, a Televisions table which contains one of each model, and then link those entries to a particular entry in the Rooms table, once for each instance of that item. I end up with something like this:

```cs
public class Television
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    // ...

    // keep track of rooms containing this model
    public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}

public class Room
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    // ...

    public virtual ICollection<Television> Televisions { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that, with this setup, you can really only link each row of the Televisions table to a row of the Rooms table once, whereas I'd like to link it, for example, 3 times. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: why not just have a quantity field against the child - television - that you can set?  So you end up with one entry, but it has a quantity of 3 for example

Comment: How can I do this while still maintaining flexibility? e.g. 2x one model, 3x another, 1x another?

Comment: you have one entry for each distinct model?  if you don't care about serial numbers, etc. you could have one entry for TV Plasma 1920x1080 with a quantity of 3, another entry for tv plasma (some other size) quanty x, etc. - so you only have one entry per distinct entity but maintain quantities.   (Unless I've misunderstood something...)

Comment: Well, each room is different. Room A has so many of each model, then room B has a different arrangement, etc. It's not that there are 3 plasma TVs, it's that Room A has 3 of model X, 2 of model Y; while room B has none of model X but 2 of model Y; etc.

Comment: you could have a distinct table of artefacts (Tvs) - e.g. Plasma TV 1920x1080, etc.  and a linking table between room & artefact - with a quantity in the joining table - so Room A could link to the plasma entry and the joining table could have a quantity of 3, Room B could link to the table with a different quantity, etc.  That way you're only entering the TVs once, and just specifying a quantity on the joining table...

Comment: That sounds like an elegant solution, but I'd love to see a code example for how such a thing would work. I only know joining tables as a concept.

Comment: you just need a table which has a primary key and foreign keys to the Room and artefact (TV); go to diagrams in SQL and drag the appropriate fields from the joining table to the primary keys of the corresponding tables and entity framework will take care of the rest for you when you build your entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make Television and Room with many to many relationship, you need to use join table for them. For example create join table call TelevisionRooms, and create quantity property in the join table. It should solve the problem. See below:

```
 public class Television
    {
        public int TelevisionID { get; set; }
        public int ModelID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    }

    public class Room
    {
        public int RoomID { get; set; }
        //
        public virtual ICollection<Television> Televisions { get; set; }

    }

    public class TelevisionRoom
    {
        public int TelevisionID { get; set; }
        public int RoomID { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public int ModelID { get; set; }
        public string ModelName { get; set; }
    }
```

Hope it will help.